# Посчитать корреляции для каждого уникального значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть исходный DF:

```
 FIRM  x1  x2
    1   4   4
    1   2   34
    1   3   4
    1   4   4
    2   4   4
    2   4   4
    2   4   4
    2   2   4
    3   3   3
    3   2   3
    3   2   2
```

Необходимо взять каждую из FIRM, взять корреляцию между x1 и x2, и вывести в новый DF.

То есть, на выходе нужно получить нечто такое:

```
 FIRM   CORR
    1   …..
    2   …..
    3   ….
```

Comment: взять каждую что?

Comment: Каждое уникальное значение из столбца FIRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
In [116]: from scipy.stats import pearsonr

In [117]: df.groupby('FIRM')[['x1','x2']].apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x['x1'], x['x2'])[0])
...\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:3038: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  r = r_num / r_den
Out[117]:
FIRM
1   -0.870388
2         NaN
3    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Да, все верно. Но как вывести значение определенное? то есть корреляцию между x1 и x2 , а не всю табличку 2*2. Потому что затем хотелось бы еще среднюю корреляцию посчитать.

Comment: Ошибку выдает ( SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character